# How can I make a new video out of specific bits from a video CD?

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a video CD (VCD), and there are specific parts I'm interested in: a few seconds here, a few seconds there. I'd like to extract only those bits, into a new video file (or files). How can I do this?

I know there are many video editing applications for Ubuntu, but there are too many to try, and they don't all accept a VCD as-is, so I'd like some help with the entire workflow.

In case there are no GUI software, I'm fine with using the commandline, as long as I don't have to read manpages in too much detail. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [**OpenShot** [image: Install Openshot]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openshot) to do this:

[image]

Just drag the file from your video CD into OpenShot; It should convert everything automatically. I don't have a Video CD to test it, but since the Video CD standard mandates it use MPEG-1, I'm quite confident it'll work just fine.

[image]

You'll use the Razor tool (3) to split your video into multiple clips, delete the unwanted ones and move them around as you like.

Comment: Thanks, this works! And it's simple enough that I was able to teach my mother. I'll wait a day or so and probably mark this as accepted.